# Error correction

Tags: exam-questions

**Catherine's grandfather always lost his balance while walking and would be found fallen on the road.**

> 1) Catherine's grandfather always
>
> 2) lost his balance while walking
>
> 3) and would be found fallen
>
> 4) on the road.

This sentence is from an error spotting exercise, Is the *would be found fallen* used in part (3) of above sentence correct ?

Comment: No, but you should probably tell us why you think it's not correct. Otherwise it's not clear why you find it confusing.

Comment: Actually I shouldn't say part 3 is *definitely* incorrect.  I would say the entire sentence is so poorly written it's hard to tell exactly which part is *most* incorrect.

Comment: Sorry I can't elucidate why I found that confusing but its just that to my ears the construction was sounding awkward.

Comment: You're right about the awkward.  Part 4 is fine, but otherwise each part contains odd words or expressions that I wouldn't use, and which make it difficult to tell you which is the "correct" answer to this exercise.

Comment: Ignoring the answer for the exercise,Please tell  How You  would  have conveyed the above information?

Comment: "Catherine' grandfather frequently had dizzy spells while he was out on his walks, and would often be found lying by the side of the road."   But even this indicates a serious medical condition, and wouldn't be allowed to happen over and over.  So it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It would be better if it said the grandfather was "resting by the side of the road while he recovered."  That indicates he's fine, but not able to walk right away.  Otherwise when someone *collapses* on the road, you call an ambulance.

Comment: May I know why the 's' of apostrophe has been omitted ?

Comment: Because I forgot to type it  :)

Comment: @Andrew Oh, All right, I thought I was missing something regarding apostrophe usage :P

Comment: 3) is a problem. I think it should be "Catherine's grandfather always lost his balance while walking and would be found fallen down on the road." [*fallen*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fallen) alone is a past participle or adjective. Some examples given don't seem to fit in your usage. You might search for some examples like yours using "fallen". I can't say it is patently wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The challenge with these kind of questions is that, all too often, they are not written by native English speakers and contain odd word choices or phrases that make the entire sentence difficult to understand.  It's hard to say which part of the sentence is *grammatically* incorrect when other parts of the sentence are *idiomatically* bizarre.

Let's start with **"always"**.  If her grandfather *always* lost his balance, why is he going out on walks?  Yes, I know older people can be stubborn, but that's relevant information which helps the sentence make sense.  You should not write a test question that raises these kind of distracting questions.

**"Lost his balance while walking"**.  I suppose you can *say* this, but a native speaker would be more likely to say the grandfather "grew *dizzy*" or "had trouble with his balance".  We would more often say "he lost his balance" when talking about a single, isolated event.  Otherwise a native speaker would use language to explain the *medical* cause for the recurring problem.

**"Found fallen (on the road)"**.  If you are *fallen* on the road, it means you can't get up -- you have passed out, you are seriously injured, or you are dead.  An elderly man who has *fallen down* but is otherwise fine would be said to be *lying down* to indicate that he is still there *by choice*, and not because the bystanders haven't yet called an ambulance.

**"On the road."**  Even this simple description is strange.  When someone is lying *on* the road, it could mean they were *in the middle* of the road -- which again raises questions of what was going on.  Were the cars just swerving around him while he was lying there, too dizzy to get up?  Or maybe it wasn't a *road* for vehicles at all, but a sidewalk or a footpath or a trail or a dirt track or some isolated place where he wouldn't be found for a while?  If so, you should say that instead, or say he was *by the side* of the road or *on the sidewalk/footpath*.

Put it together and it sounds like you have an elderly man with a *serious* medical condition who, for some unknown reason, is *allowed* to take long walks by himself, on which he *always* collapses and, for some significant length of time, is *ignored* by passing traffic.  This is probably not what the writers intended, but nevertheless it's what that sentence *implies*.

Here's how I would have written it:

> Catherine's grandfather frequently had dizzy spells while he was out on his walks, and would often be found resting by the side of the road (until he felt strong enough to continue).

This is much less troubling.  The grandfather just gets dizzy from time to time and has to rest.  He doesn't need an ambulance; he's just old.